# Kenwood Dnx891hd rca output fuse

Tags: capacitor, pcb, resistors, diodes, fuses

I have a Kenwood dnx891HD and I've had problems with it for years I finally sent it in due to protect mode and they sent me a picture and told me it was this rca output fuse on the circuit board and I was wondering how I could replace it or bridge it.

[image: circuit board fuse]

Comment: Desoldering the faulty one, source a new component, solder it on. You don’t want to bridge it.

Comment: Would you happen to know what kind of fuse that is, what its called or where to get one

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic here, but I can suggest you search for the service manual which may give some hints.

Comment: Ok...um.. would you happen to know what kind of fuse it is ?   And I've looked everywhere but can't find a service manual for this model

Comment: An SMD 0805 fuse might fit in, but as long as voltage and trip current are unknown this ends in guess work.

Comment: I ended up finding a service manual for the 892 but everything's virtually the same, the fuse was a 4 amp and it gave me a part number which I checked for but was discontinued and it gave me an equivalent so I'm gonna get that one and put it in. Also I'm going to ground it separately and not use the car harness

Comment: Does anyone have any info in general to these kinds of fuses? Like is that resin it's encased in? How to remove it? Why pcbs have those kind? Etc....  I appreciate all the help so far